# Remove zeros and doble comparison in pairwise condensed matrix

Tags: r, matrix, data-structures, comparison

I'd like to create a specific pairwise comparison matrices using a data frames. For this I have:

Data frame with 5 products (deltametrina,fipronil,imidaclopride,sulfluramida,tiametoxam) and 2 inviduals notes(Indv)

```
Indv<-c(1,2)    
deltametrina<-c(1,1)    
fipronil<-c(5,3)    
imidaclopride<-c(7,5)   
sulfluramida<-c(3,7)
tiametoxam<-c(9,9)
DF<-cbind(Indv,deltametrina,fipronil,imidaclopride,sulfluramida,tiametoxam)
DF
```

After, I create a pairwise comparison matrices, my rule is the variable with highest value minus smaller numeric number of each variable. But final matrix for each individual (Indv) in a list object.

```
df <- as.data.frame(t(DF[, -1]))
out <- lapply(df, function(x) outer(x, x, function(x, y) abs(x-y)))
out2 <- lapply(out, function(m) {
  dimnames(m) <- list(rownames(df), rownames(df))
  m
})
```

Finaly, 
I ordered the matrix in a specific format:

```
out3 = list()

for(i in seq(1,length(out2)))
{
out3[[i]]=as.vector(out2[[i]])

names=
paste(
rep(rownames(out2[[i]]),each=ncol(out2[[i]])),
rep(colnames(out2[[i]]),nrow(out2[[i]]))
,sep='_')

names(out3[[i]])=names

}

[[1]]
  deltametrina_deltametrina       deltametrina_fipronil  deltametrina_imidaclopride 
                          0                           4                           6 
  deltametrina_sulfluramida     deltametrina_tiametoxam       fipronil_deltametrina 
                          2                           8                           4 
          fipronil_fipronil      fipronil_imidaclopride       fipronil_sulfluramida 
                          0                           2                           2 
        fipronil_tiametoxam  imidaclopride_deltametrina      imidaclopride_fipronil 
                          4                           6                           2 
imidaclopride_imidaclopride  imidaclopride_sulfluramida    imidaclopride_tiametoxam 
                          0                           4                           2 
  sulfluramida_deltametrina       sulfluramida_fipronil  sulfluramida_imidaclopride 
                          2                           2                           4 
  sulfluramida_sulfluramida     sulfluramida_tiametoxam     tiametoxam_deltametrina 
                          0                           6                           8 
        tiametoxam_fipronil    tiametoxam_imidaclopride     tiametoxam_sulfluramida 
                          4                           2                           6 
      tiametoxam_tiametoxam 
                          0 

[[2]]
  deltametrina_deltametrina       deltametrina_fipronil  deltametrina_imidaclopride 
                          0                           2                           4 
  deltametrina_sulfluramida     deltametrina_tiametoxam       fipronil_deltametrina 
                          6                           8                           2 
          fipronil_fipronil      fipronil_imidaclopride       fipronil_sulfluramida 
                          0                           2                           4 
        fipronil_tiametoxam  imidaclopride_deltametrina      imidaclopride_fipronil 
                          6                           4                           2 
imidaclopride_imidaclopride  imidaclopride_sulfluramida    imidaclopride_tiametoxam 
                          0                           2                           4 
  sulfluramida_deltametrina       sulfluramida_fipronil  sulfluramida_imidaclopride 
                          6                           4                           2 
  sulfluramida_sulfluramida     sulfluramida_tiametoxam     tiametoxam_deltametrina 
                          0                           2                           8 
        tiametoxam_fipronil    tiametoxam_imidaclopride     tiametoxam_sulfluramida 
                          6                           4                           2 
      tiametoxam_tiametoxam 
                          0
```

But, I'd like to create a final matriz without zeros and double comparasion like:

```
[[1]]

- [deltametrina, fipronil, 4]
- [deltametrina, imidaclopride, 6]
- [deltametrina, sulfluramida, 2]
- [deltametrina, tiametoxam, 8]
- [fipronil, imidaclopride, 2]
- [fipronil, sulfluramida, 2]
- [fipronil, tiametoxam, 4]
- [imidaclopride, sulfluramida, 4]
- [imidaclopride, tiametoxam, 2]
- [sulfluramida, tiametoxam, 6]


[[2]]

- [deltametrina, fipronil, 2]
- [deltametrina, imidaclopride, 4]
- [deltametrina, sulfluramida, 6]
- [deltametrina, tiametoxam, 8]
- [fipronil, imidaclopride, 2]
- [fipronil, sulfluramida, 4]
- [fipronil, tiametoxam, 6]
- [imidaclopride, sulfluramida, 2]
- [imidaclopride, tiametoxam, 4]
- [sulfluramida, tiametoxam, 2]
```

This is possible?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this also (with your `out2`):

```
library(reshape2)
lapply(out2, function(x) {x <- as.matrix(x); 
                          x[lower.tri(x, diag=FALSE)] <- 0; 
                          df <- subset(melt(x), value>0); 
                          df[order(df$Var1),]})
```

to get the output:

```
$V1
            Var1          Var2 value
6   deltametrina      fipronil     4
11  deltametrina imidaclopride     6
16  deltametrina  sulfluramida     2
21  deltametrina    tiametoxam     8
12      fipronil imidaclopride     2
17      fipronil  sulfluramida     2
22      fipronil    tiametoxam     4
18 imidaclopride  sulfluramida     4
23 imidaclopride    tiametoxam     2
24  sulfluramida    tiametoxam     6

$V2
            Var1          Var2 value
6   deltametrina      fipronil     2
11  deltametrina imidaclopride     4
16  deltametrina  sulfluramida     6
21  deltametrina    tiametoxam     8
12      fipronil imidaclopride     2
17      fipronil  sulfluramida     4
22      fipronil    tiametoxam     6
18 imidaclopride  sulfluramida     2
23 imidaclopride    tiametoxam     4
24  sulfluramida    tiametoxam     2
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sandipan Dey!!

Answer (score 1):

Below gives a list of dataframes. Each set has 20 rows although your example results only shows 10. I don't know what rule is applied to reduce to 10. I don't work much with matrices so I am not sure what the final matrix structure should be.

```
library (reshape2) # for the melt function to make wide data frame narrow
library(dplyr) # for simple sort and filter

result <-  lapply(out2, function(x) {
    melt(x)  %>% filter(value!=0) %>%  arrange(Var1, Var2)})

> result
$V1
            Var1          Var2 value
1   deltametrina      fipronil     4
2   deltametrina imidaclopride     6
3   deltametrina  sulfluramida     2
4   deltametrina    tiametoxam     8
5       fipronil  deltametrina     4
6       fipronil imidaclopride     2
7       fipronil  sulfluramida     2
8       fipronil    tiametoxam     4
9  imidaclopride  deltametrina     6
10 imidaclopride      fipronil     2
11 imidaclopride  sulfluramida     4
12 imidaclopride    tiametoxam     2
13  sulfluramida  deltametrina     2
14  sulfluramida      fipronil     2
15  sulfluramida imidaclopride     4
16  sulfluramida    tiametoxam     6
17    tiametoxam  deltametrina     8
18    tiametoxam      fipronil     4
19    tiametoxam imidaclopride     2
20    tiametoxam  sulfluramida     6

$V2
            Var1          Var2 value
1   deltametrina      fipronil     2
2   deltametrina imidaclopride     4
3   deltametrina  sulfluramida     6
4   deltametrina    tiametoxam     8
5       fipronil  deltametrina     2
6       fipronil imidaclopride     2
7       fipronil  sulfluramida     4
8       fipronil    tiametoxam     6
9  imidaclopride  deltametrina     4
10 imidaclopride      fipronil     2
11 imidaclopride  sulfluramida     2
12 imidaclopride    tiametoxam     4
13  sulfluramida  deltametrina     6
14  sulfluramida      fipronil     4
15  sulfluramida imidaclopride     2
16  sulfluramida    tiametoxam     2
17    tiametoxam  deltametrina     8
18    tiametoxam      fipronil     6
19    tiametoxam imidaclopride     4
20    tiametoxam  sulfluramida     2
```